# How to add a border around a chart created via ggarrange and increase space between combined charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to draw Numa Nodes CPU and memory usage.

[image: my chart]

There are 4 numa nodes in my example with CPU and memory usage charts in each.

The problem is - in every Node there could be many CPU values (1 bar for each core, 20 cores in my example) and only one memory value, so I had to use different width of charts (CPU charts are wider than memory's). Because of that annotation text (NUMA XX) does not look like it was the middle of chart now. I can't really say which Node's memory bar is that.

I think I need to split numa nodes from each other using border or background color so CPU and memory of each Numa node were together. Also I think I need to decrease space between CPU and memory inside numa node and increase space between numa nodes. How to do that?

My code:

```
library(dplyr)

library(ggplot2)

library(ggpubr)

library(tidyr)

memory_df <- structure(list(NumaNode = c("00", "00", "01", "01", "02", "02", "03", "03"),
                         CounterName = c("TotalMemory", "UsedMemory", "TotalMemory", 
                                      "UsedMemory", "TotalMemory", "UsedMemory", "TotalMemory", "UsedMemory"),
                    Value = c(48, 45.55, 48, 46.38, 48, 46.54, 48, 47.39)),
                    row.names = c(NA, -8L),
                    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

memory_y_scale <-  memory_df %>% filter(CounterName=='TotalMemory') %>% select (Value) %>% max() + 6

cpu_df <- structure(list(NumaNode = c("00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
                                      "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
                                      "00", "00", "00", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
                                      "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
                                      "01"), Counter = c("00", "01", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
                                                         "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", 
                                                         "08", "09", "00", "01", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
                                                         "17", "18", "19", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09"
                                      ), Value = c(10.79, 5.85, 9.55, 9.71, 9.77, 4.73, 4.62, 10.92, 
                                                   3.55, 10.3, 1.38, 6.28, 5.42, 4.45, 10.09, 3.42, 10.14, 4.34, 
                                                   9.48, 4.17, 5.2, 3.85, 10.17, 8.49, 10.36, 8.06, 10.01, 8.42, 
                                                   9.12, 7.6, 1.98, 2.41, 4.72, 3.19, 4.74, 3.66, 4.28, 9.83, 5.78, 
                                                   10.18)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                               "data.frame"))



# plot function =======================================================================

plot_numa = function(num){
  
  # memory plot =====================
  
  memory_filtered_df = memory_df %>% filter(str_detect(NumaNode, num))
  
  memory_plot  <-  memory_filtered_df %>%
    filter(str_detect(CounterName, "Memory")) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = CounterName, values_from = Value) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = "") ) +
    geom_col(aes(y = TotalMemory), fill = "white", color = "black") +
    geom_col(aes(y = UsedMemory), fill = "#00FF66FF", color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(TotalMemory, "GB"), y = TotalMemory + 5 ), color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(
      label = paste(UsedMemory, "GB"),
      y = ifelse((TotalMemory-UsedMemory > 10), UsedMemory + 5, UsedMemory - 4)),
      color = "black") +
    theme_bw() +
    ylim(0, memory_y_scale) +
    labs(x = "Memory", y = "")
  
  # cpu plot =====================
  
  cpu_filtered_df <-  cpu_df %>% filter(str_detect(NumaNode, num))
  
  if (nrow (cpu_filtered_df) == 0 )    {
    cpu_filtered_df <- cpu_df %>% filter(str_detect(NumaNode, "00"))
  }
  
  cpu_plot <-  cpu_filtered_df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Counter)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = 100), fill = "white", color = "white", alpha = 0) +
    geom_col(aes(y = Value), fill = "#00AFBB", color = "black") +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(x = "CPU, % Processor Time", y = "") 
  
  
  ggpubr::ggarrange(cpu_plot, memory_plot, ncol = 2, widths = c(4,1)) %>% 
    ggpubr::annotate_figure(top = paste("        NUMA",num))
  
}

numa_numbers <- unique(memory_df$NumaNode)

ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = map(.x = numa_numbers, .f = ~plot_numa(num = .x)))
```

Here is example of borders I want. I am unhappy with it because 4 tiles too close to each other and borders are overlayed.

[image: example of result]

Comment: I'm a bit unclear as to what you're asking, are you wanting the  'NUMA'# to be centered above the CPU and Memory charts? Or just have it centered over the CPU chart?

Comment: @Jonni added picture.

Comment: Hi :) Have you tried to use `plot.margin` argument inside `theme()`? Ex: `theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,2,2,1), "cm"))`. This add space around the plot.

Comment: Also, if you really want to add borders around, maybe you can add "NULL" plots as suggested here: https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below some code, for the spacing part, using `plot.margin` inside `theme()`. I also changed a bit line 76, `widths`: `ggpubr::ggarrange(cpu_plot, memory_plot, ncol = 2, widths = c(2,1)) %>%` .

```
library(ggpubr)
library(tidyverse)

memory_df <- structure(list(NumaNode = c("00", "00", "01", "01", "02", "02", "03", "03"),
                            CounterName = c("TotalMemory", "UsedMemory", "TotalMemory", 
                                            "UsedMemory", "TotalMemory", "UsedMemory", "TotalMemory", "UsedMemory"),
                            Value = c(48, 45.55, 48, 46.38, 48, 46.54, 48, 47.39)),
                       row.names = c(NA, -8L),
                       class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

memory_y_scale <-  memory_df %>% filter(CounterName=='TotalMemory') %>% select (Value) %>% max() + 6

cpu_df <- structure(list(NumaNode = c("00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
                                      "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
                                      "00", "00", "00", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
                                      "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
                                      "01"), Counter = c("00", "01", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
                                                         "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", 
                                                         "08", "09", "00", "01", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
                                                         "17", "18", "19", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09"
                                      ), Value = c(10.79, 5.85, 9.55, 9.71, 9.77, 4.73, 4.62, 10.92, 
                                                   3.55, 10.3, 1.38, 6.28, 5.42, 4.45, 10.09, 3.42, 10.14, 4.34, 
                                                   9.48, 4.17, 5.2, 3.85, 10.17, 8.49, 10.36, 8.06, 10.01, 8.42, 
                                                   9.12, 7.6, 1.98, 2.41, 4.72, 3.19, 4.74, 3.66, 4.28, 9.83, 5.78, 
                                                   10.18)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                               "data.frame"))



# plot function =======================================================================

plot_numa = function(num){
  
  # memory plot =====================
  
  memory_filtered_df = memory_df %>% filter(str_detect(NumaNode, num))
  
  memory_plot  <-  memory_filtered_df %>%
    filter(str_detect(CounterName, "Memory")) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = CounterName, values_from = Value) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = "") ) +
    geom_col(aes(y = TotalMemory), fill = "white", color = "black") +
    geom_col(aes(y = UsedMemory), fill = "#00FF66FF", color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(TotalMemory, "GB"), y = TotalMemory + 5 ), color = "black") +
    geom_text(aes(
      label = paste(UsedMemory, "GB"),
      y = ifelse((TotalMemory-UsedMemory > 10), UsedMemory + 5, UsedMemory - 4)),
      color = "black") +
    theme_bw() +
    ylim(0, memory_y_scale) +
    labs(x = "Memory", y = "") +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.01,2,2,0.01), "cm"))
  
  # cpu plot =====================
  
  cpu_filtered_df <-  cpu_df %>% filter(str_detect(NumaNode, num))
  
  if (nrow (cpu_filtered_df) == 0 )    {
    cpu_filtered_df <- cpu_df %>% filter(str_detect(NumaNode, "00"))
  }
  
  cpu_plot <-  cpu_filtered_df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Counter)) +
    geom_col(aes(y = 100), fill = "white", color = "white", alpha = 0) +
    geom_col(aes(y = Value), fill = "#00AFBB", color = "black") +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(x = "CPU, % Processor Time", y = "") +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.01,0.01,2,0), "cm"))
  
  
  ggpubr::ggarrange(cpu_plot, memory_plot, ncol = 2, widths = c(2,1)) %>% 
    ggpubr::annotate_figure(top = paste("        NUMA",num))
  
}

numa_numbers <- unique(memory_df$NumaNode)

ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = map(.x = numa_numbers, .f = ~plot_numa(num = .x)))
```

And the output:
[image]

Comment: Looks not bad but now there's a lot of space between CPU and Memory bars inside of NUMA. They still do not look like they were together.

Comment: @Maxim you can play around with values passed to `plot.margin` to change that according to your needs.

Comment: @Maxim, changed margins to take into account your comment, please see the updated answer.

Comment: Is it possible to use background colors? each node - white background, space between - white?

Comment: @Maxim, I do not know. It is important to keep in mind that you have plots that you can edit using `theme()` functions and the function that put these plots all together on a "blank" page. If you want to change **plot** background, you can use `theme( plot.background = element_rect(fill = "yourcolor"))`. But I do not know how to change the background of the "page" that gathers these plots.

Comment: You might want to look at other packages like cowplot that also have functions to gather plots.